# Getting error while copying files between Azure BLOB container using AzCopy

Tags: azure, azcopy

I am trying to copy all files from one container to another. I am using AzCopy to accomplish this task.

AzCopy command as below:

```
azcopy copy "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/customers" "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/archive" --recursive
```

Error:
[image]

Alternatively is it possible to Move files between containers?

Comment: Have you given the rbac role to your account? In the `Access control (IAM)` of your storage account in the portal, e.g. `Storage Account Contributor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal) to grant your user account the RBAC role `Storage Blob Data Contributor` in your account or your containers.

Besides, there isn't a "move" operation for Azure Blob Storage, you need to delete the original container after copying it.